# Gravity Forms Dynamic Confirmation From Fields

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a single form on multiple pages that I need to have custom confirmation redirects for tracking Google Conversions.

I am close to getting it working except that the url does not come out correctly.

I want it to be: `https://example.com/location/city-name/product-name/`

However when I submit the form I am getting this: `https://example.com/location/$location/$product` and so it is not going to the correct page obviously.

I suspect it has something to do with the way Gravity Forms outputs the data. Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_8', 'dynamic_confirmation', 10, 4 );

function dynamic_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {
  $product = rgar( $entry, 'location_product');
  $location = strtolower(rgar( $entry, 'location_title'));
  $location = str_replace(',', '', $location);
  $location = str_replace(' ', '-', $location);

  $url = 'https://example.com/location/'.$location.'/'.$product;

  $confirmation = array( 'redirect' => $url );

  return $confirmation;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following action after submission instead of the confirmation filter:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_8', 'dynamic_confirmation', 10, 2 );
function dynamic_confirmation($entry, $form ){ 
     $product =$entry['2'];//replace 2 with field number with product name
     $location = strtolower($entry['3']);//replace 3 with field number with location title
  $location = str_replace(',', '', $location);
  $location = str_replace(' ', '-', $location);
    header('Location: https://example.com/location/'.$location.'/'.$product);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes! Thanks for the alternative method.